# SQL merge columns with specific criteria

Tags: sql

Suppose you have two tables:

```
         table customer     
id  username    startcity   finalcity
1   a               S1         F1
2   b               S2         F2
3   c               S3         F3
4   d               S4         F4
```

and

```
table client        
id  username1   startcity1  finalcity1
5   k               K1          F2
6   l               S6          F3
7   m               S2          F9
8   n               S4          G8
```

If i select a username from table customer, i want to create a new table which for the first row will have username,startcity and finalcity corresponding to the username i selected and the following rows will consist of the username , startcity1 and finalcity1 from table client which either has startcity1 == startcity or finalcity1 == finalcity

e.g.. if i select username b from table customer, the new table should be:

```
new table   
b   S2  F2
m   S2  F9
k   K1  F2
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically a `union all` query.  However, SQL statements are not guaranteed to return results in a particular order, so you need an explicit ordering:

```
select id, startcity, endcity
from (select c.id, c.startcity, c.endcity, 1 as ordering
      from customer c
      where c.username = USERNAME
      union all
      select  cl.id, cl.startcity, cl.endcity, 2 as ordering
      from client cl join
           customer c
           on cl.startcity = c.startcity or cl.endcity = c.endcity
     ) c
order by ordering;
```